# Xcode - 2 View Controller and 2 Swift Files and read TextField from View Controller 1 from View Controller 2

Tags: swift, textfield, viewcontroller

I have 2 View Controller

1) View Controller 1
2) View Controller 2

In "View Controller 1" have "Text Field 1" = 10 ( viewcontroller1.swift )

In "view Controller 2" have "Text Field 2" = 10 ( viewcontroller2.swift )

The question is in "View Controller 2" I have "Button" to calculate "Text Field 1" + "Text Field 2" = 20.

So in "viewcontroller2.swift" file how i write the code ?

Thanks all the help.

[Text Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgAoi.png)

Comment: do you first visit viewcontroller1 and then to viewcontroller2? if so then you can use segue

Comment: I just want to display the answer in "View Controller 2" label. The label show answer is "20" when I click the Button at "view Controller 2".

Comment: so you are asking how to pass data from first textfield to second view? If that is the case then i have solutions

Comment: my xcode in swift is this 

  @IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        
        let answer1 = Double(tf2.text!)
        
        if answer1 != nil {
        label1.text = "\(answer1!)"
        } else {
        label1.text = "Must Number"
        }

Comment: I attached the Text Field Image link above. Thanks.

Comment: You know what this is called, lazy. GOOGLE HOW TO CODE FOR IOS. Maybe you'll actually learn something rather rely on people to write the base line of intro to iOS code for you. Do your homework, and if a legitimate issue appears, then ask it here with code...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I google and get the answer for it. See my latest posts. Thanks for all the helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A:
when push viewcontroller2, pass Text Field 1 value

B:
pass Text Field 1 refrence to vc2

C:
pass weak viewcontroller2 to vc2

Comment: How > can you provide the steps ? Thanks. I swift.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "VC2") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2;

        svc.toPass = tf1.text

    }
}
```

apply above on View Controller 1

---

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


var toPass:String!
```

---

apply above on View Controller 2

apply below as well

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    dummyLabel.text = toPass
}
```

and lastly on "Storyboard Segue" the Identifier : "VC2"